# natbib problem with Inspire bibitem

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

Hi I go a bit of a problem (I'm helping a friend in writing her thesis). I'm almost there, only that it's not compiling

here's the (example) code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}

\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

this is a very old galaxy, as found in \citet{Ellerbroek:2013bba}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

    \bibitem{Ellerbroek:2013bba}
      L.~E.~Ellerbroek, A.~Bik, L.~Kaper, K.~M.~Maaskant, M.~Paalvast, F.~Tramper, H.~Sana and L.~B.~F.~M.~Waters {\it et al.},
      ``RCW36: characterizing the outcome of massive star formation,''
      arXiv:1308.3238 [astro-ph.SR].

    \end{thebibliography}

    \end{document}
```

The compiler says:

Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

The same happens if I try other natbib options and \bibiographystyle available.
I took the bibitem from Inspire.het (a notorious scientific papers search engine that many of you will probably know)

Can anyone help me? thank you very much

Comment: There is no way for `LaTeX` to determine the author and year from the information you have provided. The [natbib package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib) documentation explains how to provide this via an optional argument to `\bibitem`. However, I would recommend using `BiBTeX` to do it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the bibliography will be built entirely by hand, i.e., *without* BibTeX and an external bibliography file, right? If this impression is correct, there's no need -- in fact, it's pointless -- to provide a `\bibliographystyle` instruction. Do keep loading `natbib` with the option `authoryear`, though.

Because you're building the entire bibliography by hand, it is up to you to provide the information that's needed by `natbib`'s `\citet` and `\citep` commands to generate authoryear-style citation callouts. This information should be given in the optional argument of each `\bibitem` instruction. For instance, you should write

```
\bibitem[Ellerbroek et~al.(2013)]{Ellerbroek:2013bba}
   L.~E. Ellerbroek, A. Bik, L. Kaper, K.~M. Maaskant, M. Paalvast, F. Tramper, H. Sana, L.~B.~F.~M. Waters {\em et~al.},
   ``RCW36: Characterizing the outcome of massive star formation,''
   arXiv:1308.3238 [astro-ph.SR].
```

Observe that there's *no space* between "et~al." and "(2013)" in the optional argument of `\bibitem`.

With this setup, the instruction `\citet{Ellerbroek:2013bba}` generates the callout "Ellerbroek et al. (2013)", and `\citep{Ellerbroek:2013bba}` generates (Ellerbroek et al., 2013). (And, because `hyperref` is loaded, the citation callous will be made into hyperlinks to the corresponding bibliographic entries.)

Comment: thank you very much for your answers
No, I'm not going to build the bibliography by hand but, as I already mentioned, I'm going to get the information pre assembled from Inspire.het (the \bibitem{} that I used is an example).
I'm sure that what I need is possible, as most physics scientific articles are in this format and I seriously doubt that the corresponding authors build 70-references articles' bibliographies all by hand
thank you once again

Comment: @andrea - Thanks for this follow-up. I'm not personally familiar with `Inspire.het`. However, if `Inspire.het`'s entries are already formatted as `\bibentry` items (like the Ellerbroek example you provided), then most of my answer still applies: you need to provide the citation-relevant pieces of information in the optional argument of each `\bibentry` instruction.